# PHP Script fetching only first row of address field from the MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am building a page where addresses are being fetched from database and displaying all locations, but the code is only showing first address field from the database.
i have even searched google, and all related questiong, but nothing seems to be working.

As output i am getting first location in the address field, and that location is being displayed on the google map.
what i need to do is to fetch all rows of addresses from address field in the database and display them on google map(multiple markers).

is there any way so that i can fetch all the addresses and store them in an array in the database and display those addresses from ' var address ' on the google map.

could any body please help i am new to this concept.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
      <? 
      error_reporting(0);
     include('dbcon.php');
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT address FROM markers");
     $new_array = array();
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $new_array[] = $row['address'];  
     }

    $add_js = json_encode( $new_array );
     ?>
    <script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var side_bar_html = "";
    var icon1 = "prop.png";
        var icon2 = "build.png";
        var locations = <?php echo $add_js ?>;
    //alert(locations);        
    function geocodeAddress(i) {
            geocoder.geocode(
                        {
                            'address' : locations[i]
                        },
                        function(results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, i);
                            } else {
                                alert('Geocode was not successful for the 
                              following   reason: '
                                        + status);
                            }
                        });
                      }   

       function createMarker(latlng,i) {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    map : map,
                    icon : icon1,
                                    position : latlng
                                });

                 //add info window

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
               marker.setIcon(icon2);
           infowindow.setContent(locations[i]);
           infowindow.open(map, marker);
           title: 'Property!'
                });

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
              marker.setIcon(icon1);
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i]); 
              infowindow.close(map, marker);
              title: 'Property!' 
         });

             //end of adding info window

             return marker;
              }


              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom : 10,
              center : new google.maps.LatLng(28.6139, 77.2089),
              mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              });

             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                     size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)});

             var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

             for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
              geocodeAddress(i);

             }//end of for loop
            </script>

            </body>
           </html>
```

Comment: This question seems very similar to [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581770/markers-are-not-displaying-in-google-map-after-fetching-them-from-database). One of these questions should be closed

Comment: @ducan i have deleted that question sir.

Comment: **My code is working now so i have updated the correct code!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

`while($add[]=mysql_fetch_row($sql));`

Fetches as many rows from the SQL result and places them into an array; you'll get an array of arrays of columns.

Arrays in PHP don't have a built-in method to convert them to strings automatically, which is what will happen on the `<?=$add?>` line. You need to loop through them and print each item in the array individually, or use a method such as `implode` to convert them into a string.

What I suspect you want to do is fetch a single address from the database with a query such as

`SELECT address FROM markers LIMIT 1`

And do something like:

```
 $sql=(mysql_query("SELECT address FROM markers LIMIT 1"));

 $addressParts = mysql_fetch_row($sql);

 $add = ($addressParts && count($addressParts)) ? $addressParts[0] : '';
```

That would probably achieve what you're looking to achieve - load a single address from the database and inject it into your JavaScript.

Comment: thank you for responding. That has solved solved the address problem, but it is only fetching first address from the database, and showing single(first) address on gmap.

Comment: what is the way to fetch all row values from the database column, so that i pass that value in my script to display multiple markers.